# How can I change the path in a loop? MATLAB

Tags: matlab, loops, path

i want to change the path of a file on each iteration in a loop. How can i do it?

```
for i=1:N
    for j=1:M
          image=imread('ORDENADOR/Sample001/img001-00001.png');
    end
end
```

I want to change the Sample001 to Sample002,Sample003...until SampleN.Also i want to change img001-00001 until img001-M  . Thank you very much

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for i=1:N
    for j=1:M
          image=imread(sprintf('ORDENADOR/Sample%03d/img%03d-%05d.png',i,i,j));
    end
end
```

Answer (score 3):

Consider making a cell array of images to read

```
imgnames = {'ORDENADOR/Sample001/img001-00001.png', ...
         'ORDENADOR/Sample002/img001-00001.png' };  

for i=1:length(imgnames)
     image=imread(imgnames{i});
end
```

Alternatively, use `num2str` with format specifiers:

```
for i=1:N
    for j=1:M
         image=imread(['ORDENADOR/Sample' num2str(N,'%.3i') '/img001-' num2str(M,'%.5i') '.png');
    end
end
```